# How can I return the output from a Python script that needs to be run as root on a PHP page?

Tags: php, python, nginx

I'm messing around on my raspberry pi and I've just gotten started by installing nginx and PHP. I have a DHT11 temperature sensor hooked up to the GPIO on my Pi, and I'm using a version of this [Adafruit script](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/examples/simpletest.py) to get the values. Only difference is that it has the proper GPIO values. On my Pi (this is all on my internal network, if it matters) I have `index.php` sitting in the default nginx directory, and this is what it outputs:

```php
<?php

#echo phpinfo();
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('/home/pi/simpleTemp.py');
$out = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $out;
```

Right now, I get no output, but I'm very sure that's because the script needs to be run as root. I've added execute permissions to the file but I still get nothing. My PHP install works fine. Should I be using `shell_exec` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

To run it as root, you can make use of `sudo`.

```
<pre>
<?php

$cmd = '/home/pi/simpleTemp.py';
$out = shell_exec("sudo -u root " . escapeshellcmd($cmd));

if (is_null($out))
{
    echo "An error occurred."
    return;
}

echo $out;
```

This will run the script as root under the defaut shell. If you don't have a `$PATH` set properly, you may need to specify an absolute path to `sudo` as `/usr/bin/sudo` on most systems.

As `shell_exec()` is a bit limited with regard to error handling, we can also just use `exec()`. In this example, we'll add some more error handling as well:

```
<pre>
<?php

if (ini_get('safe_mode'))
{
    echo "Safe mode is enabled; cannot execute!";
    return;
}

$cmd = '/home/pi/simpleTemp.py';
$output = array();
$returnCode = -1;

if (!is_executable($cmd))
{
    echo sprintf("Command '%s' is not executable!", $cmd);
    return;
}

exec(sprintf("/usr/bin/sudo -u root %s 2>&1", escapeshellcmd($cmd)), $output, $returnCode);
echo implode("\n", $output);

if ($returnCode != 0)
{
    echo sprintf("An error occurred (code: %d).", $returnCode);
    return;
}
```

POSIX programs exit with status code `0` when no errors occurred.

Also note the `2>&1` here, which will redirect the output from Standard Error (`2`) to Standard Output (`1`) so that error output is not lost.

Another problem we might run into is if the `$PATH` environment variable is not what we expect. Your Python program might also depend on having a sane `$PATH`. Use the examples below to get and set `$PATH`:

```
<?php
/* To get the current $PATH. */
echo sprintf("Current PATH: %s", getenv('PATH'));

/* To set the $PATH. */
putenv('PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin');
```

Comment: Changed php to match yours, getting the error. Would it be because the python script might take a couple of seconds to run? Due to the sensor, it can take about two seconds to get data out.

Comment: Hmm, `shell_exec` should be able to handle the long runtime. Try just running: `php -r 'echo shell_exec("sudo -u root /home/pi/simpleTemp.py");'` and see what happens. If that doesn't work, try just a `php -r 'echo shell_exec("ls");'` and make sure that works.

Comment: Also make sure PHP is not running in [safe mode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php).

Comment: Would `php -r 'echo shell_exec("sudo -u root /home/pi/simpleTemp.py");'` get run inside a variable? Placed just inside index.php, it doesn't do anything. And I did a `iti_get('safe_mode')` and nothing came up there, so I guess not..

Comment: I meant to run that command from the shell prompt on the Pi manually.

Comment: Had to install php5-cli for that to work, sorry! I do get the correct output though!

Comment: Hmm, so if it works from the command line, then I wonder if it's some type of `PATH` or environment issue. You could try `/usr/bin/sudo` instead of `sudo`. I've added a second example with better error handling, as well as examples of how to get and set `$PATH`.

Comment: Tried all of that, I'm not getting anything after Current PATH: , so maybe thats it?
Also getting `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`
and an error code of 1

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
//if the script does not require root permissions you can change the
//second argument on getShell() to false. That will return a bash shell
//with permissions from www-data or apache user.

$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('/home/pi/simpleTemp.py');
```